# Criteria specific dictionaries use to decide on ordering of different senses of a given headword

Tags: discussion, resources

It's fairly common knowledge that OED lists senses of a given headword in the chronological order research has found printed evidence for: it is a *historical dictionary*.

Equally conveniently, the order adopted by (I'd say most of the) other respected English dictionaries is *frequency of use [as found by surveys]*.

However, [Webster's New World College Dictionary, Fifth Edition [2014]](https://www.yourdictionary.com/lurid) contains, for instance,

> **lurid**
>
> - (1) RARE deathly pale; wan
> - (2) glowing through a haze, as flames enveloped by smoke
> - (3) • (a) vivid in a harsh or shocking way; startling; sensational
>
>   • (b) characterized by violent passion or crime: *a lurid tale*

I assume that this dictionary is also historical.

Is there a resource (article?) showing which English dictionaries are historical, which arrange senses in the order they deem reflects frequency of usage, and any other types?

Comment: Interesting issue...it appears to be called *historical sense ordering* by lexicographers. Of possible interest: 1) https://books.google.it/books?id=oPaEAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA125&lpg=PA125&dq=dictionaries+with+historical+sense+ordering&source=bl&ots=5nUYg4pXLo&sig=ACfU3U38G78Pe_5Zc5QvSzpTfAXDKyKlng&hl=it&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiT1fHPzO3pAhW4XRUIHVY1Ck0Q6AEwBHoECAIQAQ#v=onepage&q=dictionaries%20with%20historical%20sense%20ordering&f=false 2) https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Historical_dictionary

Comment: 3) https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/8d2e/d9faa55f899d9eed37928f81ff8b9348002c.pdf

Comment: Shouldn't the original dictionary explicitly state what their editorial policy is in itw introductory material?

Comment: _Finding_ the relevant introductory material is often not too easy, Mitch.